# AngularJS directive issue with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with angularjs recursive directive.
It is showing the first key, value pair, but not showing 2nd one.
Here is the [link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh4rd8a6/) code snippet.

Here is HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <navigation menu="menu"></navigation>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And Javascript code.

```
angular.module('application', [])
    .directive("navigation", ['$compile',function ($compile) {
        return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            menu: '='
        },
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in menu">{{item.Name}}<span ng-repeat="(key,value) in item.Children"><navigation menu="value"></navigation></span></li></ul>',
        compile: function (el) {
            var contents = el.contents().remove();
            return function(scope,el){
                $compile(contents)(scope,function(clone){
                    el.append(clone);
                });
            };
        }
    };

}])

.controller('myController', ['$scope','$log',function ($scope,$log) {
    $log.log('In Controller');
    $scope.menu = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Contact",
        Children: {'user1': [{
            Name: "Testing",
            Children: {}
        },{
            Name: "More Testing",
            Children: {'user3': [{
                Name: '3rd Level',
                Children: {}
            }]}
        }], 'user2': [{
                Name: '3rd Level',
                Children: {}
        }]}
     }];
}]);
```

Please help me fix the issue that value for **user2** key of the first layer is not showing.

Comment: The jsfiddle link is missing

Comment: Sorry I was not able to add the link to the post. https://jsfiddle.net/nh4rd8a6/

Comment: Because you are passing `Children` object to the directive.

Comment: I don't think so. The values of `Children` object are passed.